# Selecting items from a Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash in Ruby that looks like this:

```
{"NameValues"=>[
    {"Name"=>"Field 1", "Values"=>["Data 1"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 2", "Values"=>["Data 2"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 3", "Values"=>["Data 3"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 4", "Values"=>["Data 4"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 5", "Values"=>["Data 5"]}
]}
```

I want to select the contents of the "Values" element by using the name from the "Names" element, e.g., locate the "Data 3" string by searching for "Field 3" etc.

Comment: You might want to look at refactoring the code that generates the hash. The hash is not very usable as it's forcing you to jump through hoops, and should/could be simplified into one where each "Name" value is actually the key pointing to the "Values" value.

Comment: Yeah I agree - unfortunately that bits out of my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method to find the hash by name:

```
hash = {"NameValues"=>[
    {"Name"=>"Field 1", "Values"=>["Data 1"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 2", "Values"=>["Data 2"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 3", "Values"=>["Data 3"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 4", "Values"=>["Data 4"]}, 
    {"Name"=>"Field 5", "Values"=>["Data 5"]}
]}

p hash['NameValues'].find{ |h| h['Name'] == 'Field 3'}['Values']
#=> ["Data 3"]
```

`find` basically iterates through the `NameValues` array until a matching element is found. You can then get the `Values` from the returned element.